# Understanding closure

Tags: javascript

I'm bit confused with closure in Javascript.

```
var updateDom = function(param1, param2, param3) {
    return function(event) {
        // Do something.
    };
};

var updateDomForMyBtn = updateDom(param1, param2, param3);
$btnX.on('click', updateDomForMyBtn);
```

But why can't I wrap it in an  anonymous function, it could be useful if I need to do something more :

```
var updateDom = function(param1, param2, param3) {
    return function(event) {
        // Do something.
    };
};

var updateDomForMyBtn = updateDom(param1, param2, param3);
$btnX.on('click', function() {
    // Do something more...
    return updateDomForMyBtn
});
```

What would be the proper way to do it ?

Comment: What makes you think you can't?

Comment: How do you define "proper"? What are the features of the OP that make it not proper?

Comment: Why don't you have look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work.

Comment: In  your click handler, you have to actually call `updateDomForMyBtn()` by putting parens after it.   `updateDomForMyBtn` is a function reference.  So `return updateDomForMyBtn` just returns a function reference from an event handler which does nothing.  Presumably you want to execute it with `updateDomForMyBtn()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **actually can** *wrap it in an anonymous function*. You just have to call `updateDomForMyBtn` at the end of that anon function instead of returning it:

```
var updateDom = function(param1, param2, param3) {
    return function(event) {
        // Do something.
    };
};

var updateDomForMyBtn = updateDom(param1, param2, param3);
$btnX.on('click', function() {
    // Do something more...
    updateDomForMyBtn();
});
```